# ASP.NET LoggedIn event IsAuthenticated = false

Tags: asp.net

I am using ASP.NET 4.0 Login control with LoggedIn event

```
protected void Login_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) // return false (why?)
    {
        string name = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    }
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
```

The event is being fired and I am catching it with debugger. The problem I have is that `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` returns `false` for some reason

After the function ends and it redirects to `Default.aspx`, if I add `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`, it returns `true`.

How come?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default behaviour, take a look at the MSDN page for this event:

Taken from the ['Remarks' section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.loggedin.aspx) [with emphasis mine]:

> The LoggedIn event is raised after the authentication provider checks the user's credentials and **the authentication cookie is queued to send to the browser in the next response**. Use the LoggedIn event to provide additional processing, such as accessing per-user data, after the user is authenticated.

This is why you see `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated=true` when you are redirected to `default.aspx`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember to save the authentication for the next HTTP request with [FormsAuthentication.SetCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxb3b282).

From MSDN:

> Creates an authentication ticket for the supplied user name and adds it to the cookies collection of the response, or to the URL if you are using cookieless authentication.